# How to restore an order status value that has been previously deleted in Magento Admin Interface?

Tags: order-status, delete, status, duplicate

I accidentally deleted an order Status which I need to recover but I don't know how.

The following image below shows the statuses before I deleted one.

[image: screenshot1]

The second image below shows the statues as they are now.

[image: screenshot 2]

I deleted the second one from the top:

```
    Pending - pending - Yes - processing [Processing].
```

I cannot add it back in because it does not allow for the status code to be used twice. I think the people who made our website created this using code somehow to achieve the functionality which we needed.

Previously, an order would come in with the status of Pending, and we could then change it to Processing when it was ready to be exported to our warehouse.

Now orders coming from Paypal and orders we take over the phone go straight to Processing which is not good.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these values back to these table

`sales_order_status` status `pending`  label    `Pending`

**and**

`sales_order_status_state`
status `pending`    state `processing`  is_default `1`